# Does this type of classification exist?

Tags: classification, dataset, data

Im fairly new to data science and trying to see if a type of classification exists for my needs.

I understand that a classification into 2 categories will look something like this:

[image]

You have 2 desired outcomes and you try to build a model that classifies as `0` or `1`. If these models are not 100% accurate then you will:

a) Miss some true values (outside edges of circles)
b) Get some of the wrong values in each category (overlaps between circles)

However, I am looking for something more like this:

[image]

In this case, I want to predict only `1`, and I dont mind if some `0`s are included but want to make sure that as many as possible `1`s are predicted.

In my mind, this is effectively just widening the orange circle (the classification of `1`s) in the picture.
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of formulating the problem with Venn diagrams you could also look at a simple two by two table. Usually the problem is formulated graphically in a different way (see picture below from Wikipedia page). If you are interested in just predicting the occurrence of the value 1 you are just focusing on the sensitivity (or true positive rate) of your classification algorithm.
This is rater straightforward within a ROC analysis framework, you could just select a minimun value for the classifier threshold. However, this comes at the cost of very low specificity. You should also consider the cost-benefit ratio of your sensitivity/specificity results.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity

[image]